# enable previous dates of one week on date picker in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar

i am trying to disable all the dates on `datepicker` except dates 7days before from current date  but it disables all the dates. it works fine when i un-comment the commented code lines and comment the else part "return true" line.
but it disables the weekends too. so how can i achieve it without using `noweekends(currentdate)`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            {
                var currentDate = new Date();
                $("#StartDate").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates });
                $("#StartDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
                $("#StartDate").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);

            }
        });

        $(function () {
            {

                var currentDate = new Date();
                $("#StartDte").datepicker({ beforeShowDay:DisableSpecificDates });
                $("#StartDte").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
            }
        });
        function DisableSpecificDates(currentdate) {

            //var weekenddate = $.datepicker.noWeekends(currentdate);
            var difference;
            var minDate = new Date();
            var todaydate = new Date();
            var d = todaydate.getDate();
            var prevdays = 0;
            difference = d - 6;
            if (d <= prevdays && d > 0) {
                minDate.setDate(difference);
            }
            else {
                minDate.setDate(difference);
            }
            var datemin =new Date (minDate);
            var day = todaydate.getDay();
            switch (day)
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:

                    prevdays = 4;
                    break;

                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:

                    prevdays = 2;
                    break;

                case 6:
                    prevdays = 3;
                    break;
            }
            datemin.setDate(datemin.getDate()+1);
            var dateOfMin = (minDate.getDate()) - prevdays - 1;
            minDate.setDate(dateOfMin);
            if (currentdate > todaydate || currentdate < minDate) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            //return weekenddate;    
        }
```

Comment: stupid mistake i was returning true instead of [true]

Comment: try solution given might help you, you dont need this complex logic , just to restrict user from selecting certain date , you can easily do with minDate and maxDate setting...let me know i you are trying something else

Comment: actually i have to enable previous 7 days while skipping Saturday and sunday

Comment: so you want to disable saturday and sunday ??, i am not sure but you can cobile mindate,max date thing with beforeshowdate function

Comment: you can just add this `beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends`  with mindate, maxdate will reslove issue of disabling weekend

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to set date range as example below , so below will fix date range and also disable weekends

```
$( "#datepicker" ).
   datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D", beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
```

[check datepicker :  Date Range](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

or try like this

```
$('#date-time-picker').datepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    useCurrent: false,
    showClose: true,
    minDate: '2018-03-09',
    maxDate: '2018-03-15',
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends 
})
```

but here you need to give mindate and max date from script , for simplicity i hardcoded date